# Nginx and uwsgi not working with unix socket

Tags: unix, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to use unix socket in nginx and uwsgi but its not working for me but without unix socket its working.

```
uwsgi --socket test_django_uwsgi.sock --protocol=http --virtualenv /home/ubuntu/myenv27/ --wsgi-file wsgi.py
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name www.example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    access_log  /home/ubuntu/test_django/nginx-access.log;
    error_log  /home/ubuntu/test_django/nginx-error.log info;


    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/test_django/static/media/;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/test_django/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
    #uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8000;
    uwsgi_pass  unix:///home/ubuntu/test_django/test_django/test_django_uwsgi.sock;
    include  /home/ubuntu/test_django/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

uwsgi.log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.1 (64bit) on [Fri Sep 18 08:41:28 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 17 September 2015 21:29:55
os: Linux-3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-172-31-35-204
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/test_django/test_django
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7858
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :test_django_uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:01:27)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/myenv27/
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1e66460
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1e66460 pid: 13117 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 13117, cores: 1)
```

when i m trying to access www.example.com:8000 my site dose not open.

Comment: i also checked error log but nothing there..

Comment: What does mean *site does not open*? 404/502/503 or time out error?

Comment: @Anatoly This webpage is not available error.. Chromium's connection attempt to www.example.com was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

Comment: hmm, ok. In case of wrong configured uwsgi you should see 502, if  location configured not right so 404 is what displayed instead. Otherwise problem is on a lower level (DNS) or network.

Comment: @Anatoly client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 202.89.104.26, server: 0.0.0.0:80 in nginx error log

Comment: permissions in the socket maybe?

Comment: @PerroVerd i changed permissions also but noo succss